# Relay / Convert CAS protocol into SAML

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, cas

I have a customer who can only provide me SSO data through the CAS protocol.  My software only accepts LDAP / SAML / many others, but not CAS. (I use the "Auth0" service).

Is there any way to install a CAS client, or even Apereo CAS Server (which supports CAS procotol *AND* SAML, etc), on one of my servers, as a intermediate hop between my code and the customer?

```
(Customer) --- CAS --->  (??? magic ???) --- SAML ---> (Auth0) --- REST ---> (my app)
```

Comment: Which version of SAML did you refer to? Looking at this [doc](https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/protocol/SAML-Protocol.html), I found that CAS does have full support of SAML 1.1, but for SAML 2.0, it is limited to Google Apps Integration.

Comment: Thanks for looking!  SAML 1.1 - and yes, CAS the server does support the version of SAML I want, and I've learned it supports "delegating":  https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/integration/Delegate-Authentication.html

So I'm trying that route!

Comment: Cool! Please keep me posted!

Comment: This looks promising: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/authentic2/2.1.20  
But on install, it's asking for a newer version of django (1.8), but the docs specify an older version (Python 2.7 with Django 1.5).  I'll play with it some more, but it looks a little abandoned =(

Comment: Or this - more recent: https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback-component-cas